# Orthogonal Projection and Orthogonal Complement Are Orthogonal To One Another

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

$U^{\perp}=\{X\in \mathbb{R}^n | \langle X,Y\rangle=0\forall Y\in U\}$, where $X,Y$ are vectors and $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

$proj_U(X)=\frac{X\cdot E_1}{||E_1||^2}E_1+\ldots +\frac{X\cdot E_m}{||E_m||^2}E_m$, where $\{E_i\}$ is some orthogonal basis, where $X$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n,$  and $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$

How would I go about showing that these two are orthogonal to one another?

I know I need to show that the dot product of these should equal zero, but I'm having some trouble getting started. Any advices will be appreciated.

Comment: I think it would help to introduce the terms you are using. What's $X $, for example.  What's $ u$?

Comment: I've added what each variable means. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Can you state explicitely what are the two subspaces that you have to prove being orthogonal?

Answer (score 0):

You have left out the crucial detail that the $E_i$ form an orthogonal basis of $U$, not of $X$. Thus $\mathrm{proj}_U(X) \in U$.
But by construction, every element of $U^\perp$ is orthogonal to every element of $U$.
Thus every element of $U^\perp$ is orthogonal to $\mathrm{proj}_U(X)$.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about how we know that if $\{E_i\}$ is an orthogonal basis of $U$, it means that $\operatorname{proj}_U(X)\in U$? Thanks.

Comment: This is the **definition** of $\mathrm{proj}_U(X)$. Projection onto the subspace $U$ you better give you an element of the subspace $U$, that's why it is defined that way. You can see that if the $E_i$ are elements of $U$, then $\mathrm{proj}_U(X)$ is a finite sum of elements of $U$. If you let one of the $E_i$ not be an element of $U$, then the sum definitely would not be an element of $U$.

Comment: In short, we don't deduce that $\{E_i\}$ is an orthogonal basis of $U$, it must be given to us. It is a requirement of the definition of $\mathrm{proj}_U(X)$ that the $\{E_i\}$ we take in the formula form an orthogonal basis of $U$.

Comment: Would it be possible to work it out algebraically, with something along the lines of: $(v-proj_w(V))\cdot (proj_w(V))=0\implies v\cdot proj_w(V)-proj_w(V)\cdot proj_w(V)=0\implies \ldots$? Or would this way not be valid?

Comment: What are you trying to work out? $\mathrm{proj}_U(X) \in U \implies \forall v \in U^\perp, \langle v,\mathrm{proj}_U(X)\rangle = 0$. This is just applying the definition of $U^\perp$ to $Y = \mathrm{proj}_U(X)$.